# How to get one or certain number of columns in json format in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

Below is my code.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
return json_encode($users);
```

I want to get only one column or specific number of columns in JSON format. 
I am getting this output:

```
[{ "user_id":1,"email_id":"john@gmail.com","name":"John David" }]
```

I want only **user_id** as JSON format data. 
How can I get it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('user_id')->get();
return json_encode($users);
```

or this

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get(['user_id']);
return json_encode($users);
```

Also it would probably make your life easier to use `User` model class so you could then do this

```
$users = User::select('user_id')->get();
return json_encode($users);
```

or this

```
$users = User::get(['user_id']);
return json_encode($users);
```

Comment: It Worked. Thank You... :)

Comment: Please mark answer as correct than so question is closed :)